# NGUI Why UICamera.currentCamera is returning null?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ngui

I found we can't assign `UICamera.currentCamera` to a field variable in NGUI
as the `Camera.main`, we have to assign it every time in `Update()` which I think may cause a performance issue:

this works

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestUICamera : MonoBehaviour {


    private Camera cam;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 point = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Debug.Log(" pos is :" + point);
        }

    }
}
```

But when change to `UICamera.currentCamera`, it won't work

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestUICamera : MonoBehaviour {


    private Camera cam;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        cam = UICamera.currentCamera; //changing the camera to UICamera Here.
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 point = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Debug.Log(" pos is :" + point);
        }

    }
}
```

And the console gives an error:

```
 NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 TestUICamera.Update () (at Assets/TestUICamera.cs:20)
```

And this works, but I think there maybe some performance issue since we ask for the currentCamera and assign the variable every `Update()`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestUICamera : MonoBehaviour {


    private Camera cam;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        cam = UICamera.currentCamera;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 point = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Debug.Log(" pos is :" + point);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You keep forgetting C# tag. What do you mean by "won't work"?

Comment: sorry for that but I think it's not a c# issue more like a ngui issue，will add the tag though. By not work I mean the console throw a no reference exception， will edit to add that too ：D

Comment: "console throw a no reference exception" then it is C# and has a-lot to do with programming. C# is not required if this is just an Editor problem. I think I know what might be the problem. Maybe that's the problem...not sure but wait for my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`UICamera.currentCamera`](http://tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_camera.html#a51244d87d2cc49fd6a36a7ba3adc6c2d) variable is the last active camera that sent out the event. So if there is no event in the `Start` function, it will return `null`. When you try to use it later on, you will get the `null` exception message.

You should be using [`UICamera.current`](http://tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_camera.html#a4e0997ac051bd5012d25e43d64cd591c) since it is the first camera that processes all the events.

> And this works, but I think there maybe some performance issue since
>   we ask for the currentCamera and assign the variable every Update()

This is correct.

You have to use [`UICamera.cachedCamera`](http://tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_camera.html#a26ed6d2c8ff236c0280058ad253fa66b) if you care about performance. It is meant just for that purpose. The `UICamera.cachedCamera` variable is not static so you need instance of `UICamera` to get that. You first have to get [`UICamera.current`](http://tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_camera.html#a4e0997ac051bd5012d25e43d64cd591c) then the cached camera from it.

```
UICamera.current.cachedCamera
```

Finally, don'trust NGUI since it is a third-party plugin. You should always check for null before using the returned camera.

```
void Update()
{
    Camera cam = UICamera.current.cachedCamera;

    if(cam != null)
    {
        //Use Camera
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the full view of the mechanism :D

Comment: You are welcome. Changed the title to point to what's exactly happening so that other people with your problem can find it. You can change it back if you think it is not good.

Comment: Glad you change that, my English is poor, but I am trying to practice about that :D

Comment: I was able to understand your question the first time I read it so I don't think your English is bad. Happy coding!